# cloudformation template error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am getting an error saying

> 3/19/2018, 4:40:25 PM - Template contains errors.: Template error: Parameter 'LifecycleConfiguration' MaxLength must be on a parameter of type String

Here is my code.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: S3 Bucket Template for cloudformation
Metadata:
  Copyright:
    - 'Copyrights 2018, All rights reserved'
  Comments:
    - !Ref Description
Parameters:
  S3BucketName:
    Description: Name of the S3 Bucket
    Type: String
    ConstraintDescription: S3 BucketName must be between 3 and 63 characters in length.
    MinLength: 3
    MaxLength: 63
  LifecycleConfiguration:
    Description: >-
      Specify a number of days to keep files in the bucket, a value of 0 keeps
      the files in the s3
    Type: Number
    MinValue: '0'
    MaxLength: '365'
Resources:
  S3Bucket:
    Type: 'AWS::S3::Bucket'
    Properties:
      BucketName: !Ref S3BucketName
      LifecycleConfiguration:
        Rules:
          - Id: GlacierRule
            Prefix: glacier
            Status: Enabled
            ExpirationInDays: '365'
            Transitions:
              - TransitionInDays: '1'
                StorageClass: Glacier
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 LifecycleConfiguration:
    Description: >-
      Specify a number of days to keep files in the bucket, a value of 0 keeps
      the files in the s3
    Type: Number
    MinValue: '0'
    MaxLength: '365'
```

Use `MaxValue: 365` instead of `MaxLength: 365`